# Circular dependencies when installing glibc

Tags: centos, fedora, rpm, dependencies, glibc

I am trying to install python3-pygrib on CentOS 7. First I needed to install eccodes, libpng and pyproj. Before those libraries, I need to install glibc231. I ran into circular dependencies trying to do a yum local install with the rpm's:

```
Error: Package: glibc231-common-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64 (/glibc231-common-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64)

Requires: glibc231 = 2.31-3.gf.el7

Error: Package: glibc231-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64 (/glibc231-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64)

Requires: glibc-common = 2.31-3.gf.el7
```

I tried this:

```
 rpm -i glibc231-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc231-common-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc231-langpack-to-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

And got this:

```
warning: glibc231-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID da8b7718: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc-common = 2.31-3.gf.el7 is needed by glibc231-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64
```

I also tried --nodeps --force, and it said --force is not an option. Is there another workaround I can t?ry

Comment: "--nodeps" failed? That would be the first thing I would try. What was the error message? Are there are custom rpms on this system? Did you verify the checksums of the rpms?

Comment: --nodeps alone didn't work, the --force caused an error.

Comment: To repeat myself, what was the exact error message? Are there are custom rpms on this system? Did you verify the checksums of the rpms you tried to install?

Comment: Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Usage: yum [options] COMMAND

List of Commands:

check          Check for problems in the rpmdb
check-update   Check for available package updates
updateinfo     Acts on repository update information
upgrade        Update packages taking obsoletes into account
version        Display a version for the machine and/or available repos.


Command line error: no such option: --force

Comment: I am new to Linux, so it looks like the procedure y=to verify the checksum of rpms is to run the command rpm -K myrpm.rpm. For each one, it's missing the RSA/SHA signature, but MD5 was okay

Comment: This is the command I ran: yum localinstall glibc231-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64.rpm --nodeps --force

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've downloaded the packages, just use rpm, not yum. Like this:

> rpm --nodeps glibc231-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64.rpm

This is what I thought you were doing in the first place. (Yum is useful if you are installing packages & don't want to fiddle with all of the dependencies. If you need control over the dependencies, fall back to using rpm.)

Comment: It looks like I can't install the version of glibc on CentOS 7, but your advice led to more helpful error messages.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
rpm -ivh glibc231-all-langpacks-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc231-common-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc231-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64.rpm --force --nodeps
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).